# CSS image scrolling animation not working as expected

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to run an infinite vertical scrolling animation of logos, however the images animate a few pixels then seem to get stuck.

Does anyone have any ideas?

http://goo.gl/uqgStV

It's the vertical banner of brand logos on the right of the homepage.

Comment: How about you show us the code buddy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, setting a negative margin does not work properly on inline elements like your logo images. Try adding the following css to your page:

```
#logoScroll img
{
    display:block;
}
```